# Stretching only the Y dimension in polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile created in another program, when imported into ArcMap I found that the y axis has been squashed by a factor of 5.

What would be the easiest way of stretching it out, by a multiple of 5 without affecting the X axis?

These are complex polygons, and sorting this out in the source program is not possible.

Comment: ..hmm, my gut feeling is Arc just isn't rendering your geodata in the correct projection

Comment: Going with what @elrobis said what CRS is it using, and is it the same as ArcMap? Sometimes you can adjust the CRS for offsets, there's nothing you can do for this like that, because generally any scaling occurs on both axes.

Comment: So you think multiplying Y of every vertex by 5 will solve the problem? Or there is a point in the middle of Ys, from which stretch occurs?

Comment: Yes multiplying Y of every vertex would solve the problem, however I don't know how to do this within ArcMap.

Comment: ArcMap is technically doing things correctly, there was a bug in the program that created the shapefile.

Comment: This seems non-trivial, and off the top of my head I can't think of a way to do it (mutate Y by factor N) without a little programming. If you're not against it, I'd manipulate the question a little and tag it with ArcPy. If it were point features I think it would be doable in the GUI, but polygons can be multi-part, and each part can have interior rings. So really it's a several step problem that requires 4 loops: an outer loop over the features, an inner loop over feature parts, another inner loop over the part rings, and final inner loop to mutate each Y coordinate part of each ring. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try rubbersheeting the layer just along the y axis 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-rubbersheeting.htm

This is probably very crude and I agree with the others that fixing the problem at the source is a better solution

however if you can't 
right click grey area at the top of the screen and add the spatial   adjustment toolbar [image: Spatial adjustment toolbar]

Select the new displacement link tool 
highlighted button with arrow from green x to red x
add first link in the top left hand corner just pick a random distance but ensure the arrow goes straight up
add the second link in the top right hand corner
and third and fourth links

I just used 4 links but you could add more

open the link table (Third last icon two green lines with green and red x at ends)

Select Y Source
I copied this into windows calculator and multiplied by 5 and copied the result back to Y destination
repeat this for the 3 other links
make sure the X source and destinations are the same number

[image: Link Table here]

On the Spatial adjustment toolbar select the drop down menu and select options

Select adjustment Data select which layers you want to run the adjustment on
and select all data

Select adjustment methods and rubbersheet
Select options and under adjustment methods choose rubbersheet and under options choose nearest neighbour. Select ok.

Select adjust to rubbersheet the layer, you can also preview the data if you want.

You can also save the link table if you think you might reuse it.
[image]

Comment: Using the rubber sheet adjustment method option caused the group of polygons to take on a peanut shape; the outer edges (where I selected my source points) expand and left the centre of the shapefile to be close to the original size. However, I selected the Transformation - Affine adjustment method and it worked! I would not want to do this over and over again, but this is a good fix.